# Is it possible to load custom php-extensions in GAE?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How to compile/load custom php-extensions in Google App Engine, for example: [OAuth](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php), [Gmagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) ?

Comment: Not possible in Standard runtime (although OAuth is already included I believe). Flex runtime will allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate Google Cloud Shell (terminal icon in right top corner) in app dashboard

**This guide based on Debian virtual machine** 
**Detect distributive name**

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Swith to root

```
$ sudo su
```

Install pear

```
# apt install php-pear php5-dev
```

Install required extension, oauth, for example

```
# pecl install oauth
```

Add extension in .ini file for web and cli

```
# echo "extension=oauth.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/oauth.ini
# ln -s ../../mods-available/oauth.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/oauth.ini
```

Check if extension loaded

```
$ php -m | grep OAuth
```

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#PHP_Pure_PHP

> App Engine does not allow you to upload your own C extensions.

Google Cloud Shell console is not service machine.